# Teacher's client using Agora.io on Android

Tags: agora.io

With Agora Education on Android platform sdk, how can we set up a teacher's client? We tried to force user role from code but without success. When user log in into app is always set up as student and inside classroom we get an error saying that "there's no teacher in the room". Do we have to set teachers on web console? If yes how? And how can we manage teacher login from Android app?

Answer (score 0):

It will be very helpful if you can provide the demo app's link so that we can take a look at the demo app directly. But for you question, in order to set a user's role as a teacher(which is a broadcaster), you need to call setClientRole method and pass CLIENT_ROLE_BROADCASTER in the parameter.

API document for setClientRole: https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/API%20Reference/cpp/classagora_1_1rtc_1_1_i_rtc_engine.html#a89ca6a15d5a388f3c82038e74bad4040

Document for how to set the user role: 
https://docs.agora.io/en/Audio%20Broadcast/start_live_audio_android?platform=Android#6-set-the-user-role

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The solution is not good for us because we have seen from the Agora documentation for Android that "setClientRole()" works only in "Live Boadcast" mode and we need that the audience can transmit as well as receive.

Comment: Would you like to share the demo link so that i can take a look?